# processing: generated pdf cut off at y=1000

Tags: pdf, processing

I generate a pdf with this size in processing (using eclipse):
size(1200, 2000, PDF, "testruns.pdf");

My problem is, that the pdf only contains the content that is smaller that the y coordinate of 1000.

Everything below this is not displayed in the resulting graph.

To illustrate: the final line lines should more or less touch the right bottom of my pdf. Instead they are cut off at the middle because my pdf just ends there.

```java
 for (int i = 0; i < p.height; i++) {
    if (i%10==0)
       p.line(0,0,p.width,i);
 }
```

Where can i alter this 1000 limit?

edit:
Instead of the lines looking like this:

## 1

```java
********                                                                  
 *******                                                                  
   *****                                                                  
     ***                                                                  
       *
```

they look like this:

## 2

```java
********                                                                  
 *******                                                                  
   *****
```

edit: here is the pdf, you can see the error in it. I used the code snippet provided by George Profenza to generate the pdf. It illustrates my problem quite nicely.:  https://rapidshare.com/files/2041623366/testruns_simpletest.pdf
cheers

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to replicate you're issue. 
I've used your code in two similar instances and they worked fine:

```
package pdftest;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class PDFTest extends PApplet {

    public void setup() {
         size(1200, 2000, PDF, "testruns.pdf");
         noLoop();
         for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) if (i%10==0) line(0,0,width,i);
         exit();
    }

}
```

and

```
package pdftest;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class PDFTest2 extends PApplet {

    public void setup() {
        size(1200, 2000);
        noLoop();
        beginRecord(PDF, "filename.pdf");
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) if (i%10==0) line(0,0,width,i);
        endRecord();
    }

}
```

Both run well.

Also, I've noticed you use `p.height`, `p.line(`, etc. which makes me think you're creating an instance of a PApplet inside another Applet of some sort, but can't work out much more since I can't see the code. Try the basic I've provided, which are also available as a [zipped eclipse project](http://lifesine.eu/so/PDFTest.zip).

Maybe there is something in the way somewhere in the applet that contains your PApplet instance, or the dimension of the 'container' applet do not match the ones of the PApplet instance, not sure.

**UPDATE:**

I've tested both of my applets using eclipse helios and core.jar from Processing 1.5.1 on Windows XP.

PDFTest rendered a pdf with the same problem you mentioned, so I was able to replicate the issue. I am not sure why this happens, as it happens on Windows, not OSX.

PDFTest2 rendered the pdf correctly, but I did get a warning in the console:

```
isRecording(), or this particular variation of it, is not available with this renderer.
```

Not sure what that means to be honest. 
@nemoo 
Does PDFTest2 generate the correct pdf on your machine as well ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried it with your code directly and i get the same results as in my original code. so your example can be used perfectly to replicate my issue. i have added some ascii art above to show you what i mean. you are saying that for you the pdf is created correctly, like in my sketch #1?

Comment: @nemoo That is strange. I have attached output from my code here: http://lifesine.eu/so/PDFTestOutput.zip

Comment: The pdf you posted ready perfectly. That is strange. I will try to upload my pdf when i have access to a file hoster.

Comment: @nemoo Any luck with hosting a file ? The generated pdf should only be a few KB. Could you open yours in a text editor and share a pastebin link ? (e.g. http://pastebin.com/705K5Bm6 )

Comment: @nemoo Could you try this service and share your pdf/eclipse project ? http://wikisend.com/

Comment: i can only access pastebin so i put it there (after opening the pdf in notepad and copying the resuting text): http://pastebin.com/1biRbD70

Comment: Hmm, having issues with character encoding. Thinking sharing pdf content through pastebin isn't a brilliant idea. Could you access a free file sharing service and send a pdf link from there? (http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=free+upload+service&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Jpt&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=free+file+share+service&aq=f&aqi=g-c1g-b1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=dad6a0ea3dcab417) Also, could you send a basic eclipse project or share your source here so I can test ? Thanks!

Comment: @nemoo I've downloaded your file and it's strange. Are you sure you're using the same code ? The lines are actually drawn, but there's a clipping mask and the document/artboard size is 1200x985px, not 1200x2000px. I've spotted this by opening your pdf in Illustrator. If it's the same code that is a bit strange. What os are you using ? Also, what version of Processing ?

Comment: i am using windows xp, processing 1.5.1, eclipse helios sr2. i used your code exactly, without any changes (besides the file name).